# RLMResults to NSArray conversion in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, realm

How to take RLMResults data into NSArray in objective C,please give me the suggestion.

Comment: you have to loop through RLMResults to make an array ....

Comment: Thank you  El Captain,It is  working fine ...

Answer (score 16):

Exactly what El Captain said. There's no way to automatically convert an `RLMResults` object to an `NSArray`; you have to do it yourself.

```
RLMResults *results = ...;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (RLMObject *object in results) {
   [array addObject:object];
}
```

That being said, you should ask yourself if this is truly necessary. Realm provides a lot of great under-the-hood benefits with `RLMResults` (for example, lazy loading the data only when accessed) which is lost when you convert them to an `NSArray`. It's recommended you keep the `RLMResults` object around and work with that as much as you can, and convert to an `NSArray` only when you truly need to.

Comment: You're right. Using `RLMResults` is far more beneficial to using `NSArray` if you want the most out of Realm. Although, there are situations like the one I'm facing now where I have to add Realm support in our application and the consequences of modifying the data sources of many of our files could take me weeks to address. I'm not sure if the OP is facing the same issue, but if he isn't, go `RLMResults` all the way.

Comment: I'm in a situation where I think I have to convert to `NSArray`. I want to sort the Results with a block.

Comment: First of all I upvoted your answer as it seems good one.Tim how to change or convert NSArray to RLMResult?.I tried but it took as NSArray object and it crashed.

Comment: How to change NSArray to RLMResults?

Comment: You can’t. RLMResults is composed of Realm objects saved to disk and can only be retrieved from queries. You can’t create them yourself.